# Upload only part of file

Tags: php, upload

For a web application I am developing, I will need use PHP to upload only part of a very large file, not necessarily at the start of the file. Is it possible for me to only upload the necessary portions of the file to the server? I've tried looking into using a PUT request, but  I've only managed to confuse myself (I'm just a hobbyist, learning as I go).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

To the best of my knowledge, form submissions with a file upload involve the upload of the complete file (it has to do so before any PHP within the script targetted by the form can be executed).

If you only want to upload part of a file, this may be possible using something client-side, like Flash, to open the file, extract part of it, and then submit that part to your server.

Comment: Alright. Are there any alternatives to Flash you can think of off the top of your head, since Flash is quite expensive to develop in?

Comment: Maybe Java. You are looking for a client-side technology with browser integration. This is because the opening of the file and extracting a portion of said file has to be done within the user's computer. I am not a Flash or Java developer, so I may be off-base.